# how to pass id from a maped array object to redux action

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Lets say I have a component setup like this

```
const FormFillUp= ({ history }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const deleteHandler= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(deleteItem(id)) // Here i need the id of that mapped object in the array. 
}
 return (
        <Fragment>
      // Here I have Object with it's id 
      // then inside the object an mapped array of objects with their unique id. I want to pass that id of that object which is in the array to deleteHandler , So i can delete it from the array later.  
           <Button onClick{deleteHandler}> Maped Object , with id <Button/>
    </Fragment>
    )
}
export default FormFillUp
```

I don't know how to pass that array objects id's to delete handler dynamically. So if you know how to handle it please let me know. thanks.
I'm trying to achieve this in this way :

By involving useState and then useEffect but this is deleting the item onclick

```
onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault(setUnitId(box.id))}
```

This id get passed to unitId and then in console i can see it, But I want to do it in realtime calling the console.log(box.id) from that click button

if i console it directly from inside the button

```
onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault(console.log(box.id))}
```

then this returns correct id
But when i call the function

```
onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault(deleteItem(box.id))}
```

Then nothing happens and deleteItem function never called.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a separate function to dispatch `deleteItem` function.
Suppose;

```
function deleteItemWithId(id) {
    // Here you can dispatch `deleteItem(id)` with the id param
  }
```

Now to pass the id from array to the `deleteItemWithId` function, you can do it like that.

```
<Button onClick={() => deleteItemWithId(box.id)}>
    Delete
</Button>
```

And your code should look like this;

```
const FormFillUp= () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    function deleteItemWithId(id) {
    dispatch(deleteItem(id))
  }
 return (
        <Fragment>
       
          <Button onClick={() => deleteItemWithId(box.id)}>
             Delete
          </Button>
       </Fragment>
    )
}
export default FormFillUp
```

Finally, it passes in the box id from the array as an argument of the `deleteItemWithId` function.